# Write function comments in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

```
/********************************************************* 

 * Function Name:
 * Parameter:
 * Purpose:

 ********************************************************/
```

I always write function comments manually as above, but it seems like waste of time.

1. Are there any useful vim plugins to do this kind of things?
2. How could I map this utility to a short cut key (like '< Leader >cm') in vim?

Thank :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it by hand with abbreviations or mappings, but I'd recommend you instead to search for a snippet/template plugin that suits you. There exist [many](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Snippet_Plugin_Comparison).

BTW, there exist plugins that are able to fill javadoc, or [doxygen](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/Doxygen.md) comments based on function signatures. This goes a step further than what you're strictly looking for.

Answer (score 2):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Comment: Thanks :) snipmate was the exact one which I want to find.